# How should I say that I follow my favourite singer: "He is an idol to me" or "He is an idol for me"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, spoken-english

I follow one of my favourite singers. How should I say that I follow him?

> 1. He is an idol to me
> 2. He is an idol for me

Comment: "He's my idol" or "He's one of my idols" sounds a little more idiomatic to me.

Comment: My answer would be: He is my idol.

Answer (score 2):

"He is an idol to me  " is the correct version which I have heard the most. I can give you an example from Oxford : ‘I know that Dad was an idol to millions who grew up loving his music and his ideals.’

Hope it helps.